# how to Retrive post values with variable names in php

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I want  to use variables instead of a name in post method i already tried this code but it seems it is not right what can i do instead, this is my PHP code

```
    <?php
$answer="";
 for($i=0 ; $i<2 ; $i++){

   if(isset($_POST['{$i}'])){
$answer.=$_POST['{$i}'].",";
}
else{$answer.="0,";}
}
 echo $answer;
?>
```

and this is my form :

```
    <form method="post" action="data.php">
<lable for="1" >1</lable>
<input type="radio" name="1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="1" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="1" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="1" value="4"/><br/>
<lable for="2" >2</lable>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="4"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the variable name like that, just access it directly. It's an Array, which means it supports the idea of keys.

(I'm not 100% sure using integer numbered keys is a good idea, though. You might want to prepend them with a text value to prevent weird bugs)

```
$_POST[ $i ]
```

---

You can dynamically build them with a text prepend like this in html:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="1" />
```

And then access them like this in PHP:

```
$_POST['radio_' . $i];
```

Comment: `$i` is an integer variable. Your code would return the first element in the `$_POST` array, not necessarily the element whose string index is equal to the string representation of `$i`. `$_POST["$i"]` is the best way to go here.*

Comment: i have to generate 100 group of radio buttons and retrive theme using post method is there any way too do it with text?

Comment: Added an example of accessing them with prepended text.

Answer (score 0):

your for loop should look like this

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
```

and the POST-value shoudl be checked via

```
$_POST[$i]
```

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop will be better in this instance: For example:

```
$answer="";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $answer.= $value.",";
}

echo (!!$answer?$answer:'0,');
```

Comment: some of these post values are not set and they should have the value of 0 if i use foreach like this the outcome will not be true

Comment: Why wont it? If the value is 0 then your for loop would give the same result.